# Removing windows aliases

Tags: windows, iis, windows-server-2003

Recently, I gave some folders an alias for web sharing. The folders got cut and pasted out of their original location and then restored. The aliases were lost in the process yet when I try to reassign them the same alias it complains that the alias is taken. No other folder has these aliases only they did but that was lost in the cut and paste. Is there a system file somewhere or a registry I can edit to remove them so I can reapply them? The alias names are sensitive. The OS is Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the websites from IIS, refreshed and I was able to make the alias again.